# How to use BagOfWordsAnnotation from Stanford NLP parser?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I can not find anything related to bag-of-words in [list of annotation](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/annotators.html). I found there is the annotation class for getting bag-of-words, that I assume it is used as:

```
coreMap.get(CoreAnnotations.BagOfWordsAnnotation.class);
```

but I don't know which annotator I should enable. So far I've tried:

```
tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment, natlog, openie
```

but no luck.

How can I use `BagOfWordsAnnotation` from Stanford NLP parser?

Comment: Damn, that documentation is terrible. I searched the public repos on GitHub and can't see anyone using it. The annotation definition didn't provide any hints either.

Comment: @Michael did the same. looks like a ghost :)

Comment: @Michael fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be just using the output of the tokenize annotation? Or, a bit more sophisticated, lemmatisation output? (depending a bit on your use case) Like so, for example:

```
Properties props;
props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

public static List<String> lemmatize(String documentText)
{
    List<String> lemmas = new LinkedList<String>();
    Annotation document = new Annotation(documentText);

    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            lemmas.add(token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class));
        }
    }
    return lemmas;
}
```

I've never heard of this annotator and if it exists, I would find that a bit surprising, as it is basically tokenisation, perhaps augmented with some stopword stripping, that you could easily do yourself, or use other (less NLP-oriented and more IR-oriented) packages like Lucene.

Comment: I know how to make the bag of words, however, I saw the class and I am wondering if the library gives the results as well. While your example is fine, I would add removal of the stop words, for example, etc - hence I was expecting from library to have this feature (since there is this class in the code).